# Arzela-ascoli theorem and convergence of the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, arzela-ascoli

Let $\{f_n\}_{n}$ be a sequence of continuous real-valued functions defined on a closed and bounded interval of the real line, denoted $I$. Moreover, assume that the sequence is uniformly bounded and differentiable with uniformly bounded derivatives.

Then, by Arzela-Ascoli theorem, there exists a subsequence $K \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to a Lipschitz continuous function $f$.

Is it possible to prove something on the convergence of the derivative of $f_n$. For instance something such as:
$$
\{\dot{f_n}\} \text{ weakly converge to } \dot{f} \text{ in } L^1(I,\mathbb{R}^k)
$$

Comment: No, Lipschitz is not part of the conclusion of AA.

Comment: To be specific, say $I=[0,1]$ and $f_n(t)=\sqrt t$. Then $f(t)=\sqrt t$, which is not Lipschitz.

Comment: You are correct, I edited the statement and assumed further that $f_n$ are Lipschitz functions.